# How to split column in to 2 new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a stored procedure which select multiple columns from different tables and give me result like table below:

[image]

Now I want to edit the query so it would split the **ProdNum** column in to 2 new column **Prod First Num** & **Prod Second Num** . Final result should look like the table below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all of the keys have exactly two values, aggregation is good enough:

```
select linenum, description, min(prodnum) prodnum1, max(prodnum) prodnum2
from mytable
group by linenum, description
```

If some of them have just one value, then we can add a little more logic:

```
select linenum, description, 
    min(prodnum) prodnum1, 
    case when min(prodnum) <> max(prodnum) then max(prodnum) end prodnum2
from mytable
group by linenum, description
```

Finally: if you want to use another column to order the values, say `lineid` for example, then consider using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select linenum, description,
    max(case when rn = 1 then prodnum end) prodnum1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then prodnum end) prodnum2
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by linenum, description order by lineid) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by linenum, description
```